# Sharing constant data between views in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, data-sharing

Suppose we have Chrome extension, that uses background page, popup page, maybe some other views and content scripts. There is some constant data relating to the subject area, that has to be accessible from all views and content scripts.
What is the best practice to share this data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach is to keep all of the shared data in the background page, and access it via [getBackgroundPage](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) which is available from most contexts. If unavailable (eg. in a context script), you can use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to get at the data.

Comment: So your suggest is to define in background page `window.PI = 3.14`. Then in extension views use `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().PI` and in content scripts use something like `chrome.extension.sendRequest('giveMePI', function(PI) { /* here we have PI */ })` and again in background page: `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(req, sender, sendResponse) { if (req == 'giveMePI') { sendResponse(window.PI); } });`
Doesn't it seem too complicated for `PI`?

Comment: For that kind of stuff, you could make a constants.js file that you inject as a content script AND include from the background page.

Comment: If you add this comment as a separate answer i will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As [@BorisSmus mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052031/sharing-constant-data-between-views-in-google-chrome-extension#comment9968546_8054221), you can create a separate `constants.js` file that you include everywhere you need it.

For example, in your `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "js": ["constants.js", /* ... your other content scripts ... */]
    }
],
```

And the following at the top of `<head>` on your popup and background pages:

```
<script src="constants.js"></script>
```

This also has the benefit of not resulting in issues if one of the users of `constants.js` accidentally modifies a variable from it, since each user has their own copy.